# inserting xlsx data into oracle datababe

Tags: java, oracle

i want to store xlsx data into the oracle database, i wrote code to read it using java but, i am not able to store them into database,And how to use preparedStatement with it.
here is my code to read

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
  new File("C:\\Users\\wecme\\Desktop\\Writesheet.xlsx"));
  XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
  XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  Iterator < Row > rowIterator = spreadsheet.iterator();
  while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
  {
     row = (XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
     Iterator < Cell > cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
     while ( cellIterator.hasNext()) 
     {
        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
        switch (cell.getCellType()) 
        { 
           case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
           System.out.print( 
           cell.getNumericCellValue() + " \t\t " );
           break;
           case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            String s=   cell.getStringCellValue();

            System.out.print(s+ " \t\t ");

           break;  
        }
     }
     System.out.println();
  }
  fis.close();
```

here is the out put in console:

```
EMP ID       EMP NAME        DESIGNATION         
tp01         Gopal       Technical Manager       
tp02         Manisha         Proof Reader    
tp03         Masthan         Technical Writer    
tp04         Satish          Technical Writer    
tp05         Krishna         Technical Writer
```

i want to store them in database, can any one help me.
i wrote jdbc for this, but am not able to fix it

```
PreparedStatement ps=cn.prepareStatement("insert into table1 (empId,empName,Designatation) values(?,?,?)");

  while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
  {
     row = (XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
     Iterator < Cell > cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
     while ( cellIterator.hasNext()) 
     {
        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
        //System.out.println(cell);
       String sss=cell.toString();
       }
     }
```

how to assign exact index like ps.setString(index,sss);
please help me out.

Comment: If your Excel sheet has the same columns as database table, then you can use SQL Loader utility. You don't have to write code for it, that is unless code is your end goal.

Comment: same columns in the sense , names of the columns or datatypes

Comment: Same columns as in same datatypes in the same order. Then it would be easy for SQL loader to do this. It may have some options to load unordered columns, but I haven't used that.

Comment: @ 11thdimension can you please tell how to do this with java.

Comment: You will have to write the SQL insert query and use it with the `PreparedStatement` with the cell values as the parameters to the `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: "oracle datababe" you really love your database

Comment: thank you for replay,please do not comment try to solve it.

Comment: your problem description seems very clear to me but I have no java skills. I think this is the appropriate manual: [Database JDBC Developer's Guide 12.2](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/JJDBC/JDBC-getting-started.htm#JJDBC28068), it is for Oracle 12.2, maybe you use a lower version.

Answer (score -1):

I have to agree with 11thdimension - if you want to read data from excel file and load it into db, than you can some tool for that (maybe from Excel export data as CSV file) or you can write your code for that - I think that code you provided to us in your question is good start point.

If you want to store whole xlsx file in some column (for example of BLOB type) than although I think it is not good practice (for me it is a better solution to remember only url or file path in db) than you should have some stream where you read whole file and write it as bytes in that column. In this case look at this thread:

[Similar question](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:475021425271)

Question is not so clear and it is not enough specific, so this answer is too general.

Comment: if the question is unclear then please use comments to clarify the question. I am sure he does not want to tore the xlsx file in the database.

Comment: If you read carefully I gave him suggestions for both cases. So please read carefully answer.

Comment: One more note, I gave mine answer before additional comments - where he asked how to do in jave etc...

Comment: these were exactly the reasons why I made my first comment. From the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help): [avoid trying to answer questions which (...) are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)